# Add a CSS class to <%= f.submit %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3

My question is easy:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

Where does the class declaration go? I'm getting errors on multiple attempts.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811254/add-a-class-to-f-submit-but-keep-default-functionality

Answer (score 386, accepted):

```
<%= f.submit 'name of button here', :class => 'submit_class_name_here' %>
```

This should do. If you're getting an error, chances are that you're not supplying the name.

Alternatively, you can style the button without a class:

```
form#form_id_here input[type=submit]
```

Try that, as well.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Srdjan. One little curiosity - I've tried using `disable_with` on these submit buttons but they never seem to work. Is there a reason why that you know of? +1

Comment: Try with a hash for the options: {:class => 'class_name', :disable_with => 'Editing...' }. This'll go after the button name. It should work, or at least it's documented as that.

Comment: Note that you need to explicitly pass a string ('name of button here') as the first argument to `submit` in order to use the :class hash as in the answer above. If you don't have that string, you'll get an error message.

Comment: add class without removing default value answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811254/add-a-class-to-f-submit-but-keep-default-functionality

Comment: `<%= form.submit :class => 'class_name' %>` works, if you don't want to use name.

Comment: *"..chances are that you're not supplying the name.."* Exactly. But why name is mandatory when giving class?

Answer (score 177):

You can add a class declaration to the submit button of a form by doing the following:

`<%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-default' %>` <-- Note: there is no comma!

If you are altering a _*form.html.erb* partial of a scaffold and you want to keep
the dynamic change of the button name between controller actions, DO NOT specify a name `'name'`.

Without specifying a name and depending on the action the form is rendered the button will get the `.class = "btn btn-default"` (Bootstrap class)(or whatever `.class` you specify) with the following names:

- **Update model_name**
- **Create model_name**
  (where model_name the name of the scaffold's model)

Comment: Despite having fewer votes than the selected answer, this is the solution most people will want to use.

Comment: This is what I was trying to find

Comment: Useful, and permits adding an HTML attribute ("id" or "class," as in the example) without changing the default, Rails-generated button text.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer because it preserves the behavior of dynamically assigning text to the button ("Create" or "Update") based on the controller action

Comment: Definitely as @sixty4bit said.  Should be setting the button text in translation files, so the form can be reused across different controller actions, i.e. 'create comment' vs 'update comment'. See this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/18255633/5355691

Comment: Seems really weird that no comma should be used. Why is that?

Answer (score 34):

### Rails 4  and Bootstrap 3 "primary" button

```
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Yields something like:

[image: screen-2014-01-22_02.24.26.png]

Comment: This is actually best because specifying `nil` for the name retains the helper's default behaviour where, if it finds an instance variable for the object being created/displayed, such as `@person`, it will name the button accordingly (Update Foo or Create Foo) and also the `form_for` FormBuilder chooses the correct action. So this way you can extract the form code into a partial and use it to display the model object (if you wish to use a form to display it), update it and create a new instance as well.

Answer (score 14):

As Srdjan Pejic says, you can use

```
<%= f.submit 'name', :class => 'button' %>
```

or the new syntax which would be:

```
<%= f.submit 'name', class: 'button' %>
```

Answer (score 12):

### Add class key-value pair

```
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Comment: This worked for rails 6, but the syntax for form fields and this is different and this is crazy.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC you are right, I updated my answer, so it should be more canonical.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Rails 4 uses the 'value' attribute to control the visible button text, so to keep the markup clean I would use

```
<%= f.submit :value => "Visible Button Text", :class => 'class_name' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

both of them works
`<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>` and
`<%= f.submit "Name of Button", class: "btn btn-primary "%>`