# Add a class to f.submit but keep default functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Very simple question, I have:

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

I want to apply `class='btn'` to it. I know that I can easily do this:

```
<%= f.submit 'Button Name', :class => 'btw' %>
```

But...how do I achieve the same thing, i.e. apply a class without specifying a static name for the button?

In other words, given that I am doing this in my form partial, I want the name of the button to change according to the action being called (i.e. new, create, update, etc.). So how do I get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btw' %>
```

or even

```
<%= f.submit :class => 'btw' %>
```

Comment: After check, you don't need the first one because value is nil by default: submit(value=nil, options={})

Comment: I saw that in the API docs, which is why I tried the second first.