# Modifying <%= f.submit %>'s default CSS input class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying without much luck to get `<%= f.submit %>` to appear as the same as my other "buttons", all in a row.  I have found [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315967/add-a-css-class-to-f-submit) on modifying the class of `f.submit`, but realized upon examining its element in browser that it took on the class of `input`, regardless of which additional classes I added as option parameters, thus restricting its appearance.

Essentially, each of my other buttons has the following form:

```
<div class="sort-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><h4><%= link_to "Some stuff", some_link_path %></h4></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I was wondering if there is a way to fit all of these styles compacted into one class, and override that of the `input` class contained in `f.submit`.  Thanks.

---

For edification, this button is going to be my "Follow"/Unfollow" button used to create or destroy Relationships, which I first intend to render a `_follow_form` partial with the following code:

```
  <% if current_user.following?(@course) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
```

With each of the individual `_follow`partial looking like the following:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @course.id)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
  <%= f.submit "Follow course" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit hackish but you can always use js to submit the form so instead of using `f.submit`, change it to

```
<div class="sort-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h4><%= link_to_function "Some stuff", '$(this).closest("form").submit()' %></h4
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks like the optimum solution actually, since it fits with the rest of the buttons I made.  The only issue is I am actually intending to render a series of partials, which this button will act to `create` or `destroy ` a Relationship (I posted more code above in the question).. and I am not sure how I could use the js here for this.. thanks again.

Comment: what's wrong with changing this <%= f.submit "Follow this user" %> with the html?

Comment: can you try that again? the error is because of the quotations on the js. please try the updated answer

Comment: I actually noticed one hitch: while the top of the new follow/unfollow button align the same as the others, the bottom part always extends a bit longer than the rest.  Even when doing something like `padding-bottom: -10px` didn't work.  Im unsure whether an extra line is being added, and despite trying several options with the CSS the button still extends longer than the rest.

Comment: Thank you!  My css-fu is weak.. and this has been very helpful.