# Whats wrong with this class addition to this rails form_for?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, form-for

I am trying to style form elements within this rails form_for but continually run into syntax error, nothing i try seems to be working, can you see the problem?

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit, html: {class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Results in this error: `_form.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...buffer.append=( f.submit, html: {class: "btn btn-default btn... ...`

All sorts of variations of `class=`, `class:`, `html=>`, etc etc just seem to give errors too.

`<%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>`

results in this error:

`SyntaxError in TodoListsController#edit ...... _form.html.erb:23: syntax error,unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...uffer.append=( f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" );@... ... ^`

Passing 'form-horizontal' into `form_for` still produces an error;

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list, html => {:class => "form-horizontal"})  do |f| %>
....
....
<%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

`SyntaxError in TodoListsController#edit ... _form.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...uffer.append=( f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" );@... ... ^`

Note that if i explicitly declare a label to the submit action, e.g.;

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

Then the class gets added successfully and my bootstrap styling works. However this neither locates the primary problem nor solves it as then I can't use rails' form_for dynamic naming of the submit action.

Classes I apply to divs seem to work fine, bootstrap is loaded fine. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: You have an extra comma: `f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"` (don't use a comma after the `f.submit` call) (or eventually give `nil` as first argument)

Comment: @MrYoshiji please submit your comment as an answer, because it's the right one. Oh my, after hours and hours researching this, it was the tiniest thing!! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typo error: you have an extra comma in:

```
f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"
#       ^ extra comma
```

You should use the following:

```
f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs'
#       ^ no comma
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add label for submit button

```
<%= f.submit 'Ok', class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

**EDIT**
Another way is rewrite default value of button:

```
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-xs", value: 'Ok!' %>
```

and, as I think, here's what you're looking for:

```
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

no comma after `f.submit`

Comment: Without the attempted class addition the form works just fine without a submit action label? But I will try with a label now.

Comment: Add label and restart server

Comment: Thanks Igor, this is working now. Can you help me understand why without additional classes and without specifically declared label things work fine but as soon as you add classes you need to declare a label? Thanks

Comment: I was glad to help you, `jbk`! http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit

Comment: Igor, thanks and happy to get out of that hole, but i now realise that previously rails form_for was automatically naming that submit button based upon the action being performed, not it's not and is just being overridden for all form usages with my declared label. So this kind of solved one problem but created another, how can i retain the dynamic label naming, but whilst also being able to apply custom classes to the element do you know?

Comment: yes, you can usually do without a label! maybe you had issue because bootstrap?))

Comment: So though your suggestion helped in one sense it hasn't diagnosed the specific issue here. I'll read the APIdoc stuff now. Any other ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, I still know very little about the `ruby on rails`! You could make another way:   `<%= f.submit  class: "btn btn-default btn-xs", value: 'Ok!' %>` to rewrite default value generated button

Comment: Thanks Igor, but I need to get the class addition working without overwriting the automatic button naming facility of form_for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92867/discussion-between-jbk-and-igor-ivancha).

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"%>
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, added the specific error mssg in the main question body.

Comment: Ah, so i have to pass in such an html reference at the beginning of the form_for? What is the `bootstrap form` referring to? (doesn't work just as you wrote above.)

Comment: It will apply the bootstrap form class to your form. I am editing my above answer. You can apply that class and see the change :)

Comment: So strange, still not working!?!; 

`_form.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...uffer.append=( f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" );@... ... ^`

Comment: Have you added these changes?
<%= form_for(@todo_list, html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>

Comment: Thanks Umar, I have, see the bottom of main question body for code and returned error.

Comment: Ahh, use : before html

Comment: Afraid not Umar, still doesn't work. It seems that I needed to specifically declare a label to the submit action. See other answer on this post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92868/discussion-between-jbk-and-umar).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Umar`, your [`f.submit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-submit) [classreference is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315967/add-a-css-class-to-f-submit):

```
<%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

You'll also benefit from using a loop in your form:

```
#form
<% options = [[:title, "text_field"],[:description, "text_area"]] %>
<%= form_for @todo_list do |f| %>
   <% options.each do |option| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, class: "form-group" %>
          <%= f.label option[0] %>
          <%= f.send(option[1], option[0]) %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've tried that as per @Umar's suggestion and as per the addition in the main body of the question. Still not working :(

Comment: please see my latest changes in my answer and don't use "html" in f.submit

Comment: Thanks Rich, edited as per yours and Umar's changes, still not working unfortunately, as per edited question body.

Comment: Thanks bud, I've entered what I'd do